# Error for scanf and multiple inputs

Tags: c++, input, scanf

I'm very new to programming so please forgive my ignorance.
I have already tried to look up how to use scanf and tried various different ways to use it but I still receive an error after I try to enter the first input. When I tried to run the program with a set number it works (up until my second problem which I will get to) so I know its that first scanf. I appreciate any help offered. Here is what I'm trying to work on:

```
//C code
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //Declare variables
    char StudentName[100];
    float Avg;
    int Sum, Students, TotalStudents, TotalClasses, Classes, A, B, C, D, F;

    A=4;
    B=3;
    C=2;
    D=1;
    F=0;

    //This is where the problem begins.
    //I want to allow the user to input the number of students
    //being graded. "Enter the number of students being graded" 
    //comes up fine.
    printf ("Enter the number of students being graded.");
    scanf ("%i", TotalStudents);

    //First loop 
    for (Students = 0; Students<1; Students++){
        Avg =0.0;
        printf ("Enter Student Name \n");
        scanf ("%s", StudentName);
        printf ("Enter Number of Classes \n");
        scanf ("%f", TotalClasses);
        for (Classes = 0; Classes < TotalClasses; Classes++){

            printf ("Enter Letter Grade for Class \n");
            //The second problem starts here. I am trying to find a way to
            //allow the user to input the letter grade and add all the grades 
            //together. After that I want it to find the average for that  
            //student before moving on to the next student.
            //I know my code is completely wrong but I don't know how to correct
            //it based off of the examples I have seen 
            scanf ("%i", A || B || C|| D || F);
            Sum = Sum +  A || B || C|| D || F;

        }
    Avg = Sum/TotalClasses;
    printf ("%s's average is %f \n", StudentName, Avg); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of mistakes here:

First, wherever you use `scanf`, eg:

```
 scanf ("%i", TotalStudents);
```

Change it to  scanf ("%i", &TotalStudents);

Second, the first part of `scanf` is the format specifier, so if you have a `%f` there, the arguments should be of floating type.

```
scanf ("%f", TotalClasses);
```

Here, TotalClasses is an `int`. So, either change it to float, or change the format specifier to `%i`.

The letter grades: Assuming the input is an integer, and you want to use their sum.

```
  scanf ("%i %i %i %i %i", &A,&B,&C,&D,&F);
        Sum = Sum +  A + B + C + D + F;
```

Also, one more thing, you might want to consider some variables(like Sum) as a `float`, because the statement `Avg = Sum/TotalClasses;` is an integer division, so some values (after the decimal point, like 12/5=2.00 in integer division) might be lost.

Ideone link for complete code: http://ideone.com/ur3M2v

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//Declare variables
char StudentName[100];
float Avg,TotalClasses;
int Students, TotalStudents, Sum, Classes, A, B, C, D, F;
char c;
A=4;
B=3;
C=2;
D=1;
F=0;

//This is where the problem begins.
//I want to allow the user to input the number of students
//being graded. "Enter the number of students being graded"
//comes up fine.
printf ("Enter the number of students being graded.");
scanf ("%i", &TotalStudents);

//First loop
for (Students = 0; Students<TotalStudents; Students++){
    Avg =0.0;
    printf ("Enter Student Name \n");
    scanf ("%s", StudentName);
    printf ("Enter Number of Classes \n");
    scanf ("%f", &TotalClasses);
    for (Classes = 0; Classes < TotalClasses; Classes++){

        printf ("Enter Letter Grade for Class \n");
        //The second problem starts here. I am trying to find a way to
        //allow the user to input the letter grade and add all the grades
        //together. After that I want it to find the average for that
        //student before moving on to the next student.
        //I know my code is completely wrong but I don't know how to correct
        //it based off of the examples I have seen
 scanf (" %c", &c);
   switch(c)
 {
     case 'A': Sum+=A;
                    break;
    case 'B': Sum+=B;
                    break;
case 'C': Sum+=C;
                    break;
case 'D': Sum+=D;
                    break;
case 'F': Sum+=F;
                    break;
}

    }
Avg = Sum/TotalClasses;
printf ("%s's average is %f \n", StudentName, Avg);
}

return 0;
}
```

In order to detect empty input for StudentName, replace `scanf("%s,StudentName);` with

```
  char c= getchar();        // line 1
 fgets(StudentName,100,stdin);   // line 2
 int i = strlen(StudentName)-1;   // line 3
 if( StudentName[ i ] == '\n')   // line 4
  StudentName[i] = '\0';   // line 5
  if(i==0) {printf("exiting"); break;}  //  line 6
```

Explanation for this code:

`line 1`: This `c` is simply to store the buffer. In its previous line, we have a `\n`, so when we use fgets for input, it stores this `\n`, and doesn't take further input.

`line 2`: Here we take the actual input for our string, using `fgets`. Why not `scanf`? Because it stops taking input after encountering a whitespace, and its delimiter is newline, i.e. it keeps waiting for a newline to complete its scan.

`line 3`: We store the length of the string in `i`.

`line 4`: if condition - if the last character of string is `\n`, then...

`line 5`: Convert that last character to `\0`, because that's how strings should be terminated.

`line 6`: if condition - if the string length is `0`, i.e., user simply pressed enter, print message and break from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding on your problem, you want the user to input the letter grade - A, B, C, D, F.

Now this code right here doesn't make sense because scanf takes input %i - an integer base 10 (more infor: http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet) and assigns it after the comman.

```
scanf ("%i", A || B || C|| D || F);
```

The A || B etc... is a conditional which is why it doesn't make any sense to assign the user's integer input to a conditional...

Answer (score 0):

To use scanf you need to pass two arguments, the format of what you are scanning and the the address of the variable that you are assigning. The & operator is how to get the address of a variable. It would look like this:

```
scanf("%i", &someVariable);
```

The format is %i or %d for integers, %f for floats and %c for characters.

Also the || operator is the logic OR operator used for comparisons and should not be used like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how `scanf()` works for this to work. `scanf` takes at least 2 parameters. The first parameter will contain the type of variable that you need to capture (`%d` is an integer, `%s` is a string, `%c` is a character, etc). The second parameter contains the address of the variable that will contain what the user has entered.

Here are the sections of code that you need to replace :

`scanf ("%i", TotalStudents);` should be `scanf ("%i", &TotalStudents);`

`for (Students = 0; Students<1; Students++){` should be `for (Students = 0; Students<TotalStudents; Students++){`

```
scanf ("%i", A || B || C|| D || F);
Sum = Sum +  A || B || C|| D || F;
```

should be

```
scanf ("%i %i %i %i %i", &A,&B,&C,&D,&F);
Sum +=  A + B + C + D + F;
```

Also...

`scanf ("%f", TotalClasses);` should be `scanf ("%i", &TotalClasses);`